# How can we read multiple files from a folder in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test case which download the file in system default "Download" folder and at dynamic time I need to read this file from folder by applying filter on latest file.

Is there any way to read multiple files or files name from a folder in Cypress or in JavaScript ?

Comment: You might want to create a Cypress task. This way, you can use NodeJS File System module. Then you can call this task from your Cypress tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do that in cypress.

```
let fs = require("fs");
const fileList = fs.readFileSync('path/to/downloads/folder');
```

This will list the files name in an array. Now you can loop through it and use it.
I got this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript).

In cypress we have to work with plugins and the detailed description is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010818/why-do-i-get-error-typeerror-fs-readdir-is-not-a-function-in-cypress)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the package [cypress-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fs) (which I own) which provides functionalities from the fs module directly in cypress like so:

```
cy.fsReadDir(path, options);
```