# How to specify all subdirectories in a filepath string using String Interpolation?

Tags: cypress

In my cypress test I am using `cy.readFile()` to pick up screenshots of failing tests like so:

```
afterEach(() => {
    const screenshotsFolder = 'test-results/screenshots'
    const screenshotFileName = `${testState.feature.name} -- ${testState.currentScenario.name} (failed).png`;
    cy.readFile(
        `${screenshotsFolder}/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}`,
        "base64"
    ).then((imgData) => {
         stepResult.attachment = {
             data: imgData,
             media: { type: "image/png" },
             index: testState.currentStep,
             testCase: testState.formatTestCase(testState.currentScenario),
        };
    });
});
```

When I run a single test, the screenshot is saved like so, & is being read successfully:

`test-results/screenshots/login.feature/Login Feature -- Valid Credentials Scenario.png`

However, if I run multiple tests, then the files are stored like this:

```
test-results/screenshots/Smoke/01-Dummy/login.feature/Login Feature -- Valid Credentials Scenario.png
test-results/screenshots/Regression/02-Regression/login.feature/Login Feature -- Invalid Credentials Scenario.png
test-results/screenshots/Performance/03-Performance/login.feature/Login Feature -- Invalid Credentials Scenario.png
```

Therefore, I need to update the path in my `cy.readFile()` to look for the PNG files anywhere within the `screenshots` folder (i.e. in sub-directories).

I tried adding `**` to the filepath, but that hasn't worked:

```
cy.readFile(`test-results/screenshots/**/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}`)
```

Can someone please show me how to read all PNG files within the `screenshots` folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we read multiple files from a folder in Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386018/how-can-we-read-multiple-files-from-a-folder-in-cypress)

Comment: @agoff Thanks for your comment. But I think that's a bit too complicated a solution for what I need. I basically just want to say in that line - find all of the PNG files inside the `test-results/screenshots` folder (including subfolders)

Comment: The concept would still hold though, correct? Use `fs` to find all files in a subdirectory, then just iterate through those and feed them into `cy.readFile`. If your question is just "can readFile open multiple files?", then the answer is no. But, as shown in that link, there are ways to find multiple files and open them one by one.

Comment: @agoff I've added some more of my code to give a clearer context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a task to obtain the folder listing. Install [fs-readdir-recursive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-readdir-recursive) to search sub-folders.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const readDirRecursive = require('fs-readdir-recursive')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        readFolder(path) {
          return readDirRecursive(path)
        }
      })
    },
  },
});
```

Use it like this

```js
const screenshotsFolder = 'test-results/screenshots'
cy.task('readFolder', screenshotsFolder)
  .then(paths => paths.map(path => path.replace('\\', '/')))   // normalise windows os
  .then(paths => paths.filter(path => path.endsWith('.png')))  // filter for png
  .then(paths => {
    paths.forEach(path => {
      cy.readFile(
        `${screenshotsFolder}/${path}`,
        "base64"
      ).then((imgData) => {
        ...

  })
```