# How to check for file in download folder and if exist delete in cypress

Tags: cypress, uitest

I have to download a excel file lets say "someData.xlsx" during test execution meanwhile before downloading also have to put a check over download folder if "someData.xlsx" exist in download folder delete it before downloading the newly updated file. could someone explain how to achieve this ?

I tried this but getting fs.readdirSync is not a function

```
fs.readdirSync('./downloads').forEach((file) => {
                fs.unlinkSync(`./downloads/${file}`);
              });
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Also have you imported `fs` to your file?

Comment: node version -> v16.17.0 and yes imported fs to my file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74461689/11625850 -> Does this answer help you out at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install cypress-delete-downloads-folder by
`npm i -D cypress-delete-downloads-folder`

in plugins/index.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { removeDirectory } = require('cypress-delete-downloads-folder');


module.exports = (on, config) => {
//task to check if file exist
  on("task", {
     isFileExist( filePath ) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          let isExists = fs.existsSync(filePath)
          resolve(isExists);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    }
  });
//to remove directory
on('task', { removeDirectory });
}
```

in support/commands.js

```
require('cypress-delete-downloads-folder').addCustomCommand();
```

in your test spec file

```
const path = require('path');


describe('check for file in download folder and if exist delete', () => {
    it('delete download folder', () => {
        
        cy.task("isFileExist", { fileName: `.${path.sep}downloads${path.sep}fileName.xlsx`}).then(() => {
            cy.deleteDownloadsFolder()
        });
```

Comment: which cypress version you're using?

Comment: "cypress": "^11.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script in "scripts" section of "Package.json" like below:

```
"clear": "del /f cypress\\results\\*.xlsx"
```

which will forcefully delete the XLSX files of "cypress\results\" folder. Now, execute this before running your tests.

Refer image as I've used for deleting the JSON files in the respective folder.

[image]

Comment: Thank You Atul Kumar Sharma